# Fix windows xp bootloader from existing windows installation

Tags: windows-xp, bootloader

I have copied my Windows XP installation to a new hard drive. Now, the bootloader needs to be fixed, which can be done with a recovery disk. However, I would like to do it from another existing Windows XP installation, since my DVD drive doesn't work anymore.

How can i fix it from another windows installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible solution to fix the MBR is by using the recovery disk, but as you mentioned your drive isn't working. So you will need to burn an XP installation ISO to an USB stick and do it from there. There is no other way from another computer to fix the MBR without a recovery disk or USB.